# Segmentation fault on strtok_r

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

```
    char buffer[1000];
    recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    char *ptr;
    printf("\n%s\n", buffer);
    char searchPos[500];
    sprintf(searchPos, "mercenary %d position", ID);
    char *req = strstr(buffer, searchPos);
    if(req != NULL)
    {
        char *token;
        token = strtok_r(buffer, " ", &ptr);
        token = strtok_r(ptr, " ", &ptr);
        token = strtok_r(ptr, " ", &ptr);
        token = strtok_r(ptr, " ", &ptr);
        printf("%s\n",token);
    }
```

I have this code that produce a segmentation fault at the printf line and I can't figure out why.
buffer looks like "mercenary 2 position 15 20".
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: after `recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);` ,buffer is not nul-terminated. Also: `recv()` returns a value. Use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a handful of places that this could be going wrong - we cannot just tell you what's wrong.

`recv()` returns "*the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occured*" - you have no way of knowing if things went wrong here (unless you check the return value). Additionally, `recv()` will not nul terminate the "*string*", because as far as it knows / cares, it's just data.

`sprintf()` will write to the buffer with no regard to how long it is - don't use it unless you can guarantee there's sufficient space. Use `snprintf()` instead which will respect the length of the buffer. Also, check the return value for potential problems. Your buffer of 500x `char` does appear to be exceedingly large, however.

I'm pleased to see you are using `strtok_r()`, and not `strtok()`. You're using it wrong, but your use shouldn't really cause a *problem* per-se, according to [this unrelated Linux (not C) reference](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).

> On the first call to `strtok_r()`, `str` should point to the string to be parsed, and the value of `saveptr` is ignored. **In subsequent calls, `str` should be NULL**, and `saveptr` should be unchanged since the previous call.
>
> The `strtok()` and `strtok_r()` functions return a pointer to the next token, **or NULL if there are no more tokens**.

Finally, `printf()` is probably causing a SEGFAULT due to one of these problems:

1. `token` is NULL
2. `token` is not nul terminated, and thus `printf()` is running into the weeds.

I'd place bets on #1, as you *should* have seen a SEGFAULT at the first `printf("\n%s\n", buffer);` otherwise. I say "*should*" because you may be lucky - printing "*invisible*" garbage at this point.

Comment: It should be functional... perhaps "_not as intended_" would be better... we don't know what `strtok_r()` is doing with `saveptr`, and thus there could be a benefit to following the expected usage - performance or otherwise.

Comment: @Attie If I add a test before the print
"
if (token != NULL) {
  printf("%s\n",token);
} else {
  printf("not null");
}
" I still get the Segmentation fault.
Also, replacing str whith NULL doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

> strtok_r, if a token is found, a pointer to the beginning of the token.
>   Otherwise, a *null pointer*. A *null pointer* is always returned when the
>   **end of the string (i.e., a null character)** is reached in the string
>   being scanned.

```
char buffer[1000];

// make sure all bytes are initialized to 0
memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer)); 
// make sure there is at least one byte left that's set to 0
if( recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0) == -1 ) {
    perror("recv()");
    exit(1);
}
```

`recv` does not place a null terminator at the end of the string (whilst `printf` `%s` assumes there is one).

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what was wrong. I tried in another IDE and it worked.
Thank's for the help.